# Toggle multiple spans

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I need to control hiding/showing certain spans. I found some examples here and the basic code works. Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/user3052443/kksd014q/7/). There are two topics and when the word more is clicked on, sub-topics are shown. The problem is that all of the sub-topics are shown, not just the ones under the topic that was clicked.

I know the problem is with the same class name being used for the two div sections and if I change the class name of one of them and duplicate the jquery it will work as I want. But this code is being created using a loop function in php and there isn't a set number of possible topics. I suppose I could change the php code to create unique class names but I don't know how to add the jquery code so it will check any number of possibilities. How can this be coded?

```
    <script>
    $("#kid-1").hide();
    $("#kid-2").hide();
    $("#kid-3").hide();

    $(".more-kids").click(function() {
     $("#kid-1").toggle();
     $("#kid-2").toggle();
     $("#kid-3").toggle();
    });
    </script>

    <div class="information">
      <span><a href="http://example.com/-i-10.html">Terms</a></span>
      <span class="more-kids">more</span><br />
      <span id="kid-1"><a href="http://example.com/14.html">First Child</a></span><br />
      <span id="kid-2"><a href="http://example.com/15.html">Second Chlld</a></span><br />   
    </div>

    <div class="information">
      <span><a href="http://example.com/-i-10.html">Conditions</a></span>
      <span class="more-kids">more</span><br /><br />
      <span id="kid-3"><a href="http://example.com/14.html">Third Child</a></span><br />
    </div>
```

Comment: Since Spencer have answered I'm only posting this as a comment. You could make your code much easier to read without uneccessary span elements all over, if the links are to the same site you don't need the `http://host` part of the url, and changed the line breaks to css https://jsfiddle.net/593xjdsc/

Comment: The actual code uses a list (ul) and there is more to it than what is shown. But I will try your suggestion since I do prefer cleaner code. i appreciate the suggestion and, of course, Spencers fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are making `id`'s that are numbers, that indicates you should probably be using a `class` instead. What you could instead do is change your `id` to a `class` being `"kid"`. Then toggle the items by using `$(this).nextAll(".kid").toggle()`:

```js
$(".kid").hide();

$(".more-kids").click(function() {
  $(this).nextAll(".kid").toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="information">
  <span><a href="http://example.com/-i-10.html">Terms</a></span>
  <span class="more-kids">more</span><br />
  <span class="kid"><a href="http://example.com/14.html">First Child</a></span><br />
  <span class="kid"><a href="http://example.com/15.html">Second Chlld</a></span><br />   
</div>

<div class="information">
  <span><a href="http://example.com/-i-10.html">Conditions</a></span>
  <span class="more-kids">more</span><br /><br />
  <span class="kid"><a href="http://example.com/14.html">Third Child</a></span><br />
</div>
```